# Sending an email using sendgrid in a Django project using an HTML template

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email from my Django project using my Sendgrid account. For now, I am sending the email in the following way:

```
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("test@example.com")
to_email = Email("test@example.com")
subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)
```

The code is taken from this link:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python

Now, what I want to do this in the content section, instead of doing a text/plain email, I want to send a nicely formatted HTML email. Preferably, I want some way to reference a template and pass in a context. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty easy. You'll want to use [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string). It takes a request, template and context dictionary just like `render` but produces a string. Then pass it to `Content` and set the mime type to `text\html`.

Answer (score 1):

The **forgot_password_template.html** is html file/template and You can check this

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

message = render_to_string('forgot_password_template.html', {'bar': foo})
user.email_user("Send test email", message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout templates in django - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/

for sending a template you can use

```
from django.template.loader import get_template

html_content = get_template('html_sample.html').render({'foo': 'bar'})   
content = Content("text/html", html_content)
```